# Is it possible to extend C drive using unallocated space in another physical drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have 2 physical hard drives. One of them contains only my C drive and one of them contains other drives. All drives are primary and no extended partition exists. Is it possible to delete one of the primary drives in the second disk and add that space to the C drive on another disk using something like Windows storage spaces or some RAID technology solution?

The screenshot of Disk Management:[image]

Can I add the black unallocated space in the second Disk to the C drive in the first Disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
You can convert both disks from "basic" to "dynamic" and then you can create so-called "spanned volumes" that stretch across both disks.
But Windows doesn't allow you to do that with the existing C: drive.

Seems your only option is to get a bigger SSD. 120 GB is really tight for Windows and some applications these days.